# Understanding a simple light bulb circuit

Tags: circuit-design, safety, light

So I want to make a light fixture but I want to be safe and aware about all the details of my project before I just start plugging things in.

I have a light bulb and a light fixture that has two wires coming from it. I want to wire screw and electrical tape the bulb fixture wires to the lead and ground of a spare US male power cable that I have. Assuming I wire the lead and ground correctly can I just plug it into a wall socket or is the bulb going to shatter and am I going to end up with glass in my eyes?

Comment: Well make sure to wear protective eye wear before you start experimenting.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you have a 5V bulb and you plug it into mains, then you should see the build glowing for last time.your question needs more details too.. Such as bulb wattage, voltage available and your planned schematics..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you handle mains power, you are dealing in Code electrical.  With Code electrical, packaging is everything.

Your light fixture is designed to mount on a certain type of electrical box - typically a round or octagon box. Here is a stamped one; they also sell fancier cast ones which are round.

[image]

Take your cord to a proper electrical supply house (not Home Depot) and ask them for a proper fitting strain relief for that cord which fits a 1/2" knockout.

[image]

Tap out one of the knockouts on the box, and screw it in with a special nut. Or if using a cast aluminum box, just screw it in to a threaded port and plug the rest.

Inside the box, connect the lamp to the supply cord with plain wire-nuts (orange is probably the right size).

[image]

Or terminal blocks

[image]

If your supply cord has a safety ground pin, and your box is metal, tie it to the frame of the box and the lamp ground, if equipped.  They make green #10-32 screws to make that easy.  If your cord doesn't have ground, make sure the metal parts of box and lamp connect to absolutely nothing, and cap that off and tape it.  Never connect neutral to a chassis, ever.

Then secure the lamp to the box in the normal way.

Use light bulbs that are the correct voltage for the power you're plugging into.